# Нужна естественная сортировка

Tags: c#

```
public class NaturalStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shlwapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string s1, string s2);

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
    }
}

List<string> ListResult = new List<string>();
for(int i=0; i < 21; i++)
{
    ListResult.Add(i.ToString());
}
ListResult.Sort(new NaturalStringComparer());
File.WriteAllLines("TestList.txt", ListResult.ToArray());

//Результат 
//  0
//  1
//  2
//  3
//  4
//  5
//  6
//  7
//  8
//  9
//  13
//  11
//  12
//  14
//  15
//  16
//  17
//  18
//  19
//  20
//  10
```

А нужно чтобы все по порядку было

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. 
забыл добавить **CharSet = CharSet.Unicode**

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true)]
```